# my vbs code thats supposed to be that if you press f1 it launches calculator does not work. help pls

Tags: vb.net

i copied some code from other websites since im very new to this
the code

```
 Dim ii,aa,bb,cc,dd
 Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender, As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        Msgbox("press f1")
        If e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F1) Then
        Set aa = 90
          If aa = 90
            set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            WshShell.Run "calc"
            WshShell.AppActivate "Calculator"
          End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

it says this when i run it, "line 2 char 42, expected identifier"

??????

Comment: Try to remove `,` after `ByVal sender`.

Comment: That didnt work, it now says " Line 2, Char 41, Error: Expected ')' "

Comment: This code is vb. net, not vbscript

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code is not a vbscript !

But here is a solution to create a shortcut on your desktop with Hotkey <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

```
Call Shortcut("%WinDir%\system32\calc.exe","Calculator")
'--------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Shortcut(Application_Path,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,fso,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab,strCurDir
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strCurDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    MyTab = Split(Application_Path,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(_
    DesktopPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = chr(34) & Application_Path & chr(34)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Calc.exe"
    ObjShortCut.Hotkey = "ALT+F1"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'----------------------------------------------------------------
```